# SQL Query hangs and makes version store grow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First of, I apologize if this is the wrong place for this questions, but I haven't found any other location that might help me out.

I have a query that is running on a sql server that keeps running indefinitely and as a result the version store on SQL Server grows and tempdb grows as well. Currently I don't have the source code.

I would like to get a few pointers for where to search for the cause of this problem.
In activity monitor all I see is a process with a taskstate of `SUSPENDED`, and Wait Type of `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO_WRITELOG`. I'm running this on SQL Server 2008.

Again sorry if this is the wrong place for asking this.

/Andy.l

Comment: What kind of query (*SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE*)

Comment: It is, as far as I know a select statement getting information from more than one table, but I'm uncertain if it is performing any updates.

Comment: use SQl Profiler to see the TSQL being run...

Comment: Is Mirroring enabled on the database?

Answer (score 0):

First, I've got no experience with SQL2008, but from my experience with SQL2000, it managed itself sometimes into nasty locking situations running multicore environment. I would try rerun query with Option (MAXDOP 1). Cost you almost nothing to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

At least with older SQL Server versions a SELECT could be blocked by other sessions, so I would suspect something like that in your case (even though your mentioning the "version store" which seems to indicate that you have enabled the new snapshot isolation mode).

Running `sp_who2` will give you more details about whether it *is* a blocking problem or not